Spring JPA: Entity with embedded key is not deleted
I'm learning Spring Boot as I go and everything was fine so far using Spring JPA to manage database until I tried deleting an entity that has an embedded key.
The relevant entity is as follows:
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @Data
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @Cacheable
    @ToString
    @Builder
    @Table(name = "test_case_execution_result")
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findAll",
    query = "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findById",
    query = "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE t.testCaseExecutionResultPK.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findByTestCaseResultId",
    query =
    "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE"
    \+ " t.testCaseExecutionResultPK.testCaseResultId = :testCaseResultId"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findByTestCaseId",
    query =
    "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE t.testCaseExecutionResultPK.testCaseId ="
    \+ " :testCaseId"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findByTestRegionId",
    query =
    "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE t.testCaseExecutionResultPK.testRegionId ="
    \+ " :testRegionId"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findByDate",
    query = "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE t.date = :date"),
    @NamedQuery(
    name = "TestCaseExecutionResult.findByRelatedJob",
    query = "SELECT t FROM TestCaseExecutionResult t WHERE t.relatedJob = :relatedJob")
    })
    
    public class TestCaseExecutionResult implements Serializable {
    
    @Serial private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId protected TestCaseExecutionResultPK testCaseExecutionResultPK;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "relatedJob")
    private String relatedJob;
    
    @JoinColumn(
    name = "test_case_id",
    referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false,
    updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TestCase testCase;
    
    @JoinColumn(
    name = "test_case_result_id",
    referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false,
    updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TestCaseResult testCaseResult;
    
    @JoinColumn(
    name = "test_region_id",
    referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false,
    updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TestRegion testRegion;
    
    public TestCaseExecutionResult(TestCaseExecutionResultPK testCaseExecutionResultPK) {
    this.testCaseExecutionResultPK = testCaseExecutionResultPK;
    }
    
    public TestCaseExecutionResult(
    TestCaseExecutionResultPK testCaseExecutionResultPK, Date date, String relatedJob) {
    this.testCaseExecutionResultPK = testCaseExecutionResultPK;
    this.date = date;
    this.relatedJob = relatedJob;
    }
    
    public TestCaseExecutionResult(
    int testCaseExecutionResultPK, int testCaseResultId, int testCaseId, int testRegionId) {
    this.testCaseExecutionResultPK =
    new TestCaseExecutionResultPK(
    testCaseExecutionResultPK, testCaseResultId, testCaseId, testRegionId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (testCaseExecutionResultPK != null ? testCaseExecutionResultPK.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof TestCaseExecutionResult other)) {
    return false;
    }
    return (this.testCaseExecutionResultPK != null || other.testCaseExecutionResultPK == null)
    && (this.testCaseExecutionResultPK == null
    || this.testCaseExecutionResultPK.equals(other.testCaseExecutionResultPK));
    }
    }

This is the relevant controller:
    @RestController
    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.TestClassWithoutTestCases")
    public class TestCaseExecutionResultController {
    
    private final TestCaseExecutionResultRepository repository;
    private final TestCaseExecutionResultAssembler assembler;
    
    public TestCaseExecutionResultController(
    TestCaseExecutionResultRepository repository, TestCaseExecutionResultAssembler assembler) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.assembler = assembler;
    }
    
    @PostMapping(Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULT_REGION)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity\<EntityModel\<TestCaseExecutionResult\>\> createTestCaseExecutionResult(
    @RequestBody TestCaseExecutionResult testCaseExecutionResult,
    @PathVariable Integer tcId,
    @PathVariable Integer regionId,
    @PathVariable Integer resultId) {
    if (testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK() == null) {
    testCaseExecutionResult.setTestCaseExecutionResultPK(
    TestCaseExecutionResultPK.builder()
    .testCaseResultId(resultId)
    .testCaseId(tcId)
    .testRegionId(regionId)
    .build());
    }
    testCaseExecutionResult.setDate(new Date());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.assembler.toModel(this.repository.save(testCaseExecutionResult)));
    }
    
    @GetMapping(Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULTS)
    public ResponseEntity\<CollectionModel\<EntityModel\<TestCaseExecutionResult\>\>\> findAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.assembler.toCollectionModel(this.repository.findAll()));
    }
    
    @GetMapping(Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULTS_REGION)
    public ResponseEntity\<CollectionModel\<EntityModel\<TestCaseExecutionResult\>\>\>
    executionResultsForTestCaseInRegion(
    @PathVariable Integer tcId, @PathVariable Integer regionId) throws NotFoundException {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
    this.assembler.toCollectionModel(
    this.repository.findByTestCaseIdAndTestRegionId(tcId, regionId)));
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping(Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULT_REGION_EXECUTION)
    public ResponseEntity\<?\> delete(
    @PathVariable Integer tcId,
    @PathVariable Integer regionId,
    @PathVariable Integer resultId,
    @PathVariable Integer executionId)
    throws NotFoundException {
    Iterable\<TestCaseExecutionResult\> results =
    repository.findAllById(
    List.of(new TestCaseExecutionResultPK(executionId, resultId, tcId, regionId)));
    if (results.iterator().hasNext()) {
    TestCaseExecutionResult target = results.iterator().next();
    this.repository.deleteById(target.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK());
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    } else {
    throw new NotFoundException(
    "Test case execution result with id "
    \+ new TestCaseExecutionResultPK(executionId, resultId, tcId, regionId)
    \+ " not found");
    }
    }
    }

Have the following test where I basically create the necesary entities and then create a test case execution result which works fine. Then I proceed to delete it but fail when I expect to no longer being able to find it via the API. This is the approach that I use in all the other tests and seem to work fine in those cases. The only difference I can find so far is the key for this entity.
    @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    @Slf4j
    public class TestCaseExecutionTest {
    
    @Autowired private TestCaseExecutionResultController controller;
    
    @Autowired TestCaseExecutionResultRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired private TestRegionRepository regionRepository;
    
    @Autowired private TestCaseResultRepository resultRepository;
    
    @Autowired private TestCaseRepository testCaseRepository;
    
    @LocalServerPort private int port;
    
    @Autowired private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    assertThat(controller).isNotNull();
    }
    
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testCreateTestCaseExecutionResult() {
    TestCase tc =
    TestCase.builder()
    .className("ClassName")
    .testName("testName")
    .testMethod("testMethod")
    .description("description")
    .build();
    TestCase testCase = testCaseRepository.save(tc);
    
        Iterator<TestRegion> iterator = regionRepository.findAll().iterator();
        TestRegion region;
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
          region = iterator.next();
        } else {
          region = TestRegion.builder().regionName(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).build();
          regionRepository.save(region);
        }
        
        TestCaseResult testCaseResult = resultRepository.findById(1);
        
        // Add an execution result
        TestCaseExecutionResult request =
            TestCaseExecutionResult.builder()
                .testRegion(TestRegion.builder().id(region.getId()).build())
                .testCase(TestCase.builder().id(testCase.getId()).build())
                .testCaseResult(TestCaseResult.builder().id(testCaseResult.getId()).build())
                .relatedJob("Dummy URL")
                .build();
        
        this.restTemplate.getForEntity(
            "http://localhost:" + port + Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULTS_REGION,
            TestCaseExecutionResult.class,
            request.getTestCase().getId(),
            request.getTestRegion().getId());
        
        assertTrue(Objects.requireNonNull(controller.findAll().getBody()).getContent().isEmpty());
        
        TestCaseExecutionResult testCaseExecutionResult =
            this.restTemplate.postForObject(
                "http://localhost:" + port + Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULT_REGION,
                request,
                TestCaseExecutionResult.class,
                request.getTestCase().getId(),
                request.getTestRegion().getId(),
                request.getTestCaseResult().getId());
        
        assertThat(testCaseExecutionResult).isNotNull();
        assertThat(testCaseExecutionResult)
            .usingRecursiveComparison()
            .ignoringFields(
                "testCaseExecutionResultPK", "date", "testCase", "testCaseResult", "testRegion")
            .isEqualTo(request);
        
        assertFalse(Objects.requireNonNull(controller.findAll().getBody()).getContent().isEmpty());
        
        assertFalse(
            Objects.requireNonNull(
                    controller
                        .executionResultsForTestCaseInRegion(
                            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCase().getId(),
                            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestRegion().getId())
                        .getBody())
                .getContent()
                .isEmpty());
        
        ResponseEntity<TestCaseExecutionResultWrapper> response =
            this.restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "http://localhost:" + port + Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULTS_REGION,
                TestCaseExecutionResultWrapper.class,
                request.getTestCase().getId(),
                request.getTestRegion().getId());
        
        TestCaseExecutionResultWrapper wrapper = response.getBody();
        assertNotNull(wrapper);
        List<TestCaseExecutionResult> results = wrapper.getEmbedded().getTestCaseExecutionResults();
        assertNotNull(results);
        assertEquals(results.size(), 1);
        
        testCaseExecutionResult = results.get(0);
        
        // Delete it
        this.restTemplate.delete(
            "http://localhost:" + port + Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULT_REGION_EXECUTION,
            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK().getTestCaseId(),
            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK().getTestRegionId(),
            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK().getTestCaseResultId(),
            testCaseExecutionResult.getTestCaseExecutionResultPK().getId());
        
        response =
            this.restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "http://localhost:" + port + Endpoints.EXECUTION_RESULTS_REGION,
                TestCaseExecutionResultWrapper.class,
                request.getTestCase().getId(),
                request.getTestRegion().getId());
        
        wrapper = response.getBody();
        assertNotNull(wrapper);
        results = wrapper.getEmbedded().getTestCaseExecutionResults();
        assertNotNull(results);
        if (!results.isEmpty()) {
          ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
          repository
              .findAll()
              .iterator()
              .forEachRemaining(
                  item -> {
                    try {
                      String json =
                          objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(item);
                      log.info(json);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                      log.error("Error converting item to JSON", e);
                    }
                  });
        }
        assertEquals(results.size(), 0);
    
    }
    }


I was expecting the deleted entity not to be found afterward. I have a zip file of the project I could share but I couldn't figure out how to share it.
Update
I enabled the SQL in the settings and noticed that the delete query is never done:
Hibernate: select tcss1_0.id,tcss1_0.test_case_id,tcss1_0.test_region_id,tcss1_0.score,tcss1_0.stability,tc1_0.id,tc1_0.class_name,tc1_0.description,tc1_0.test_method,tc1_0.test_name,tcerl1_0.test_case_id,tcerl1_0.id,tcerl1_0.test_case_result_id,tcerl1_0.test_region_id,tcerl1_0.date,tcerl1_0.related_job,tcr1_0.id,tcr1_0.result,tr1_0.id,tr1_0.region_name,tr2_0.id,tr2_0.region_name from test_case_stability_status tcss1_0 join test_case tc1_0 on tc1_0.id=tcss1_0.test_case_id left join test_case_execution_result tcerl1_0 on tc1_0.id=tcerl1_0.test_case_id left join test_case_result tcr1_0 on tcr1_0.id=tcerl1_0.test_case_result_id left join test_region tr1_0 on tr1_0.id=tcerl1_0.test_region_id join test_region tr2_0 on tr2_0.id=tcss1_0.test_region_id where (tcss1_0.id,tcss1_0.test_case_id,tcss1_0.test_region_id) in ((?,?,?))
Hibernate: select tcssl1_0.test_case_id,tcssl1_0.id,tcssl1_0.test_region_id,tcssl1_0.score,tcssl1_0.stability,tr1_0.id,tr1_0.region_name from test_case_stability_status tcssl1_0 left join test_region tr1_0 on tr1_0.id=tcssl1_0.test_region_id where tcssl1_0.test_case_id=?
Hibernate: select tchil1_0.test_case_id,tchil1_0.issue_id,i1_0.id,i1_0.issue_reference,i1_0.issue_type_id,iti1_0.id,iti1_0.type from test_case_has_issue tchil1_0 left join issue i1_0 on i1_0.id=tchil1_0.issue_id left join issue_type iti1_0 on iti1_0.id=i1_0.issue_type_id where tchil1_0.test_case_id=?


Create an issue on Spring which has the attached project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/3615

For some reason, it seems Hibernate is not making the delete SQL call.

There's a project to reproduce the issue in the linked issue above which sadly was just closed without any investigation.

I know it does not solve your issue, but there is so much to simplify in this example: 1) not needed controller layer, you can create Junit Test just to test Repository layer 2) simplify the entity to hold just enough fields to reproduce the example 3) remove not needed entities for reproducing this example (Issue etc).  4) figure out which of lombok annotations you need and why

I was unable to make a simpler example to expose the issue. I simplified it as much as possible.

Well what about those things I just wrote you to remove? If you really want an answer you need to do some effort:)

There, I made the changes and updated the attached project in the linked issue.

I solved the issue using a custom repository per this tutorial. Basically I did what I usually have to do in other JPA code when I have an entity with embedded keys:

Fetch each entity referenced in the relationship.

Remove the entity from its collection and merge it.

Finally, remove the entity altogether.
public class CustomDeleteRepositoryImpl implements 
  CustomDeleteRepository<TestCaseStabilityStatus> {
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteCustom(TestCaseStabilityStatus entity) {
 TestCase testCase = entityManager.find(TestCase.class, entity.getTestCase().getId());
 testCase.getTestCaseStabilityStatusList().remove(entity);
 entityManager.merge(testCase);

 TestRegion testRegion = entityManager.find(TestRegion.class, entity.getTestRegion().getId());
 testRegion.getTestCaseStabilityStatusList().remove(entity);
 entityManager.merge(testRegion);

 entityManager.remove(entity);
 entityManager.flush();
}
}



